# SSIS Import Excel using IMEX=1 FirstRowhasColumnName reverts to True

Tags: excel, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to import an Excel file to VB studio 2005 using IMEX=1. In order to achieve this, I'm using the following connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +  @[User::Excel_path]  + @[User::Excel_name] + ";Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"
```

I have created an Excel connection and have unticked the "First Row has column Names". However, as soon as I add a Excel Source in the Data Flow the FirstRowHasColumnName reverts to True.

I've tried numerous variations in an attempt to get this to work, but it always reverts to column names in row 1. I've tried both using the default Excel table and accessing Excel via a variable Select statement.

Any ideas if there is a workaround?

I've also tried setting the registry TypeGuessRows = 0 but still no luck!

btw I'm working on a 64bit machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it eventually. Started again from scratch. Set up a new Excel connection. Unticked the initial "First Row has no columns" THEN set up the variable connection string / select statement. Previously I had set up the connection / variable connection string / select statement and only THEN gone back and unticked the initial "First Row has no columns"! Picky or what? :-) I've also found that

```
"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";"
```

works better than

```
"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"
```

Sounds logical, but the help sites on this issue that I've found seem to reference

```
"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"
```

Anyone out there have any bright ideas about this?